# How to bring Footer to bottom back?

Tags: html, css, blogger, blogspot

I was trying to draw a simple Blogspot page with HTML and CSS. I have designed some. Now I am stuck. I have a code:

```css
body{
 background-color: #5e769b;
 font: 16px/28px, arial, sans-serif; 
}
.container{
 background-color: #edeff2;
 width: 790px;
 margin: auto;
}
.header{
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 background-color: #6191dd;
 text-align: center;
}
.article{
 padding: 20px;
 text-align: justify;
 background-color: #f9f9f9;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 70%;
 float: left;
}
.sidebar {
 padding: 20px;
 text-align: justify;
 background-color: #f9f9f9;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 30%;
 float: right;
}
.footer{
 padding: 10px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #6b4edb;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 100%;
 color: #263959;
}
.footer,
a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="header">
  <h1>welcome</h1>
  <h2>test blog</h2>
 </div>
 <div class="article">
  <h2>Article</h2>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
 </div>
 <div class="sidebar">
  <h2>sidebar</h2>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
 </div>
 <div class="footer">
  <h4>CopyRight @ <a href="#">footer</a></h4>
 </div>
</div>
```

This code is not letting the footer at the bottom. Footer is with the sidebar.

I want footer at the bottom of the container as shown in below image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IREuq.jpg

What changes should I make in CSS or HTML?

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). It's hard to read, prevents text-based searching, and lowers the overall presentation value of the post.

Comment: If you want a footer at the bottom of the page regardless of where the body ends, you can just use the `position: fixed;` with alignment options to set it.

Answer (score 0):

You put your "footer" in a div. you should use the html tag .

So take off the < div class="footer" > thing and then go after the < /body > tag and write:

```
<footer class="footer">
    <h4>Copyright @ <a href="#">Footer</a></h4>
</footer>
```

Comment: Actually, I am watching the video from Youtube. I know basic HTML and CSS. This is the link of the video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xImAlKa6jsQ According to this video, he did not use the <footer> tag. He used <div> tag with the class footer. And his code works fine. Below comment shows my whole code. My code is the same as the video's code but I don't get my footer at the bottom of the container.

Comment: Due to long code, I am using the W3schools' editor for the code. https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G3OEMU5XYV1P

Answer (score 0):

put the `<div>` like this before `<div class="footer">`.

```
<div class="footerToBottom"></div>
```

and add **css** code for this segment:

```
.footerToBottom{
    clear:both;
    display:block;
    width:0 !important;
    height:0 !important;
    min-height:0 !important;
    min-width:0 !important;
    margin:0 !important;
    padding:0 !important;
    overflow:hidden
}
```

```css
body{
 background-color: #5e769b;
 font: 16px/28px, arial, sans-serif; 
}
.container{
 background-color: #edeff2;
 width: 790px;
 margin: auto;
}
.header{
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 background-color: #6191dd;
 text-align: center;
}
.article{
 padding: 20px;
 text-align: justify;
 background-color: #f9f9f9;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 70%;
 float: left;
}
.sidebar {
 padding: 20px;
 text-align: justify;
 background-color: #f9f9f9;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 30%;
 float: right;
}
.footer{
 padding: 10px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #6b4edb;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 100%;
 color: #263959;
}
.footer,
a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
}
.footerToBottom{
 clear:both;
 display:block;
 width:0 !important;
 height:0 !important;
 min-height:0 !important;
 min-width:0 !important;
 margin:0 !important;
 padding:0 !important;
 overflow:hidden
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="header">
  <h1>welcome</h1>
  <h2>test blog</h2>
 </div>
 <div class="article">
  <h2>Article</h2>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
 </div>
 <div class="sidebar">
  <h2>sidebar</h2>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
 </div>
 <div class="footerToBottom"></div>
 <div class="footer">
  <h4>CopyRight @ <a href="#">footer</a></h4>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know the basics of HTML and CSS. I am following this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xImAlKa6jsQ I tried the same. But he gets the result but I am not getting. He did not use what you use above .footerToBottom class.

Comment: AmirBill, one more thing, can you explain a little bit that what is !important mean here? I have searched the web for this but I want you to explain what each line means. It would be great.